# Onfocus Autoplay in videogular

Tags: video, ionic-framework, onfocus, videogular

I'm trying to fetch all the videos by using ng-repeat. Everything is working fine except when it loads all the videos starts playing. And I want the app to play only the video which are in focus.

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

add attribute to all videos 
`vg-auto-play="false"`

and then on hover event change it to true.